# Formatting html and css whilst repecting browser font settings

Tags: html, css, browser

I have 2 html files test.html and test1.html that use a common CSS file(test.css).

```
<html>
<head><link type="text/css" href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" /></head>
   <body>
  <p>Ta da Ta da</p>
  <a href="test1.html">test1</a>
   <body>
 </html>
```

**test.html**

```
<html>
  <head><link type="text/css" href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" /></head>
     <body>
     <p>Blah Blah</p>
     <a href="test.html">test</a>
     <body>   
</html>
```

**test1.html**

1. I open test.html in firefox. I use ctrl++ to zoom in and enlarge the fonts.
2. I then clicked on test1 link and navigated to test1.html. The page opens with the default font size in the browser. It does not remember my last page font zoom ratio I set in browser. 
   I could not figure how to do it in CSS. I see every other site has this facility. I am missing something basic. Can someone advise me what I should fill in my CSS to get the browser zoom ratio to be propagated across pages?

/Suresh

Comment: Are you asking how to set the font size using CSS?

Comment: (s)he's asking how to preserve the user agent's zoom level when navigating from one page to another, I'd presume? My IE9 seems to preserve this though, so it may be specific to a browser (version) and particular types of links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summary:** don't worry 'bout it! If you deploy the two files to the *same site* all browsers will remember zoom level while navigating.

---

**Long version:**
I would venture a guess that this is browser specific, and outside of your control. But if you're going to deploy the two files to one site, it may not be a problem (see below).

If I run a few tests on my PC I notice:

- **IE9** will keep the UA zoom level constant in a single browser tab, no matter where and how you browse
- **FF 13** and **Chrome 21** only keep the UA zoom level constant if you navigate around on the same web site (e.g. Stack Overflow), **but** they will reset to 100% zoom when you navigate to a new site (the "two html files on your pc" example in the quesion behaves the same)

You won't be able to control this with CSS I think. But you may not need to. If you're going to deploy your html files to a single website (so not just loose files on your PC) it shouldn't be a problem either, because then the zoom level won't reset upon navigating.

Comment: I was accessing the files directly from the local filesystem. When I put the files on a web server, the browser respects my zoom level. As you said, zoom level settings of the browser cannot be propagated with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

this the functionality of browser ctr++ to zoom you can't use it in you project.

if you want to increase the size of font of the body then use

```
 body 
{
  font-size: 100%; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sites that provide font size functionality don't use the zoom feature on the browser - your code cannot control that.

Instead, they use a baseline font size, and base the rest of the sizes on it, by specifying relative sizes instead of absolute.
For example, you can write

```
p {
   font-size: 120%;
}
```